# Add and/or option to Drupal Views' Contextual Filters?

Tags: 7, views

How can I add the "and/or" option to Drupal Views' Contextual Filters panel? I added it to Filter Criteria, but I can't seem to get it for Contextual Filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by installing [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) module. By default contextual filters are in AND condition.

> The module provides a views plugin which modify query to support OR
>   conditions for contextual filters.